# Check that two elements aren't in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to input elements #Core and #Price **that cannot share a parent element**. I need to test that both of them are not in focus and when they are not run a function.

I thought I could just do a check to make sure when one blurs the other isn't given focus like so:

```
$('#Core').blur(function() {
    if(!$("#Price").is(":focus")) {
        getSellingPrice()
    }
});$('#Price').blur(function() {
    if(!$("#Core").is(":focus")) {
        getSellingPrice()
    }
});
```

But this seems to fire even when I give focus to the other input node. My guess is that when the blur happens it checks the seconds focus before its yet been selected. But I am uncertain as to how to change the code to get the desired behavior of making sure both elements aren't in focus before triggering the function call.

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this or insight into why this current code isn't working are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How could two elements be in focus at the same time? Am I missing something key from your question?

Comment: They could not be. The idea is one element is in focus and when it loses focus I want to check that the other element did not pickup focus before performing the getSellingPrice().

Comment: Sadly, you cannot consistently check what element was moved to reliably across browsers. Not only are there issues getting event information consistently, there are also issues when tabbing, if you do it all in one movement. 

There is a property that does this: explicitOriginalTarget, but it's only available in Firefox and I believe now IE.

Therefore, a timeout is necessary, as per @adeneo's solution. I suggest you accept his answer, it's the most reliable way to achieve it at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check that the active element is neither

```
var elems = $('#Core, #Price').blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ( elems.toArray().indexOf(document.activeElement) === -1 ) {
            getSellingPrice();
        }
    });
});
```

But you'll need a timeout to make sure the focus is set etc.

Comment: This is a solid answer and I believe the only current way to reliably achieve this, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Blurring an element passes focus to the body element before transferring it to a sub element clicked. Horrible as may be a one shot timer can be used to decouple blurring with checking what element was clicked. *Concept code* triggered by blur events (translate to your coding standards, jQuery and application as needed):

```
function blurred(el)
{
    setTimeout(checkFocus, 4); // ( 4 == Firefox default minimum)
}
function checkFocus()
{  var a = document.getElementById("a");
   var b = document.getElementById("b");
   var infocus = document.activeElement === a || document.activeElement === b;

   if(infocus)
      console.log( "One of them is in focus");
   else
      console.log(" Neither is in focus");
}
```

HTML

```
a: <input id="a" type="text" onblur="blurred(this)"><br>
b: <input id="b" type="text" onblur="blurred(this)">
```